# Подсчет checkbox в калькуляторе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Более менее довел калькулятор до ума.
Главная трудность с чекбоксами:
Нужно значения выделенных чекбоксов прибавлять к общей сумме с условием: если чекбокс снят, то отнимать от суммы значение. Подскажите как это можно сделать?

И вопрос по радиокнопкам:
Если уже выбрана радиокнопка, введена площадь и произошел расчет суммы, при переключении на другу радиокнопку возможно ли пересчитывать сумму исходя из значения актуальной?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calculator_total span").text("0");

  var totalSum = 0;
  var lastFloor = 0;
  var lastRoof = 0;
  var lastWalls = 0;
  var lastService = 0;
  $('.floor').on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      $(".input_size_floor").css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
  $("#inputFloor").on("change", function() {
    var inputFloor = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($("input[name='floor']:checked").val());
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
      $("#inputFloor").each(function() {
        totalSum = totalSum - lastFloor;
        totalSum += inputFloor;
        lastFloor = inputFloor;
      });
    }
    $("#calculator_total").find('span').text(totalSum);
  });
  $('.roof').on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      $(".input_size_roof").css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
  $("#inputRoof").on("change", function() {
    var inputRoof = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($("input[name='roof']:checked").val());
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
      $("#inputRoof").each(function() {
        totalSum = totalSum - lastRoof;
        totalSum += inputRoof;
        lastRoof = inputRoof;
      });
    }
    $("#calculator_total").find('span').text(totalSum);
  });
  $("input[name='service']").click(function() {
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
      var strServiceType = parseInt($("input[name='service']").val());
      totalSum = strServiceType;
    });
    $("#calculator_total").find('span').text(totalSum);
  });
});
```

```css
.box_calculator {
  background: url("./images/box_calculator_bg.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.box_calculator h2 {
  margin: 40px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #004487;
}

.box_calculator .section {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #CD1F40;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section {
  padding: 20px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .head {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .head span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #383838;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap h3 i {
  color: #CD1F40;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #383838;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap p.checked {
  background-color: #f8ffb0;
  border: 1px solid #e4eb9f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap div.input_group,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap div.help {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .content input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .help {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  padding: 10px 10px 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .help a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #383838;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #4c4c4c;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .help a:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #005db9;
  border-color: #005db9;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_floor,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_roof,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_walls {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_floor p,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_roof p,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_walls p {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_floor td,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_roof td,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_walls td {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_floor input,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_roof input,
.box_calculator .section .left_section .wrap .input_size_walls input {
  border: 1px solid #0053a5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #004487;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section ul {
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section ul .nav-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section ul .nav-item a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #004487;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #004487;
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section ul .nav-item a.active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #004487;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 68, 135, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 68, 135, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 68, 135, 0.7);
}

.box_calculator .section .left_section ul .nav-item:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px dashed #004487;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 20px;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content {
  display: table-cell;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #total_head {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #383838;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calculator_total {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #383838;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calculator_total span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #004487;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calculator_total i {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calculator_submit {
  text-align: center;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calculator_submit button {
  background-color: #CD1F40;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #b91f3e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calculator_submit button:hover {
  background-color: #004487;
  border: 1px solid #004487;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 68, 135, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 68, 135, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 68, 135, 0.7);
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calc_phone {
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #383838;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #calc_phone:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(184, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(184, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(184, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #status_message {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #status_message .alert-danger {
  color: #721c24;
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  border-color: #f5c6cb;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.box_calculator .section .right_section .section_content #status_message .alert-success {
  text-align: center;
}

.tip {
  padding: 20px;
}

.tip .tip_title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tip .tip_title i {
  color: #CD1F40;
}

.tip .tip_content p {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="calculator_form" class="box_calculator">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2><i class="far fa-ellipsis-v-alt"></i> Калькулятор стоимости ремонта</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 p-0">
        <div class="left_section">
          <div class="head">
            <span>Рассчитайте стоимость ремонта</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="pills-floor-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-floor" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-floor" aria-selected="false">Полы</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="pills-roof-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-roof" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-roof" aria-selected="false">Потолки</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active show" id="pills-service-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-service" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-service" aria-selected="true">Электрика и сантехника</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-floor" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-floor-tab">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="input_group floor content">
                  <h3>Выберите тип пола:</h3>
                  <p class="checked"><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Плитка</p>
                  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Ламинат</p>
                  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Паркетная доска</p>
                  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Линолеум</p>
                  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Ковролин</p>
                  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Половая доска</p>
                  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Пробковое покрытие</p>
                  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Теплый пол</p>
                  <div class="input_size_floor" style="display: block;">
                    <p><strong>Площадь пола:</strong></p>
                    <input size="3" maxlength="3" type="text" id="inputFloor" name="inputFloor" value="0"> кв.м.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-roof" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-roof-tab">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="input_group roof content">
                  <h3>Выберите тип потолка:</h3>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="350">Натяжной</p>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="800">Гипсокартонный</p>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="1200">Подвесной</p>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="850">Армстронг</p>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="920">Реечный</p>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="670">Грильято</p>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="225">Кассетный</p>
                  <p><input class="roof" type="radio" name="roof" value="1350">Покраска</p>
                  <div class="input_size_roof">
                    <p><strong>Площадь пола:</strong></p>
                    <input size="3" maxlength="3" type="text" id="inputRoof" name="inputRoof" value="0"> кв.м.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="pills-service" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-service-tab">
              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="input_group service content">
                  <h3>Выберите тип работ:</h3>
                  <p class="checked"><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="350">Установка выключателей</p>
                  <p class="checked"><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="800">Установка электрического щитка</p>
                  <p class="checked"><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="1200">Установка автомата</p>
                  <p><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="850">Установка розеток</p>
                  <p><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="920">Разводка труб водоснабжения</p>
                  <p><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="670">Установка полотенцесушителя</p>
                  <p><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="225">Установка унитаза</p>
                  <p><input class="service" type="checkbox" name="service" value="1350">Установка ванны</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 p-0">
        <div class="right_section">
          <div class="section_content">
            <div id="total_head">Итого</div>
            <div id="calculator_total"><span id="calculator_sum">350</span><i class="far fa-ruble-sign"></i></div>
            <p>Получите скидку <span class="text_bold rem_red">25%</span> при заказе ремонта под ключ.</p>
            <p id="val_phone"><input type="checkbox" id="calc_key" name="calc_key" value="Ремонт под ключ"> Ремонт под ключ</p>
            <p><input type="tel" id="calc_phone" name="calc_phone" placeholder="Введите ваш номер телефона"></p>
            <div id="calculator_submit"><button class="submit" type="button">Отправить расчет</button></div>
            <div id="status_message"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обернем чекбоксы в контейнер, делегируем обработчик "onchange" и при каждом изменении суммируем чекнутые.
Думаю Вам не составит труда сумму из моего примера прибавлять/отнимать от Вашего результата :)

```js
const $container = $('#js-cks-container')
const $result = $('#js-result')

$container.on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
  let sum = 0
  $container.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    sum += Number(this.value) || 0 // если value не корректно
  })
  $result.text(sum)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="js-cks-container">
  <input type="checkbox" value="10"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="10"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="10"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="10"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="10"/>
</div>

<div id="js-result">0</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам общий случай таких перерасчётов (**upd**:  если на странице несколько калькуляторов, то логичнее производить расчёты отталкиваясь от контейнера):

```js
$('.calc').on('click', function () {
 let $calc = $(this).parent().find('.calc'), // работаем от контейнера
 sum = 0;
  $.each($calc, function (idx) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      sum = sum + parseInt($(this).val());
    }
    $('#sum').text(sum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calc">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-value" class="calc" value="10" />
  <input type="radio" name="radio-value" class="calc" value="20" />
  <input type="radio" name="radio-value" class="calc" value="30" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-value[]" class="calc" value="10" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-value[]" class="calc" value="20" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-value[]" class="calc" value="30" />

  <span id="sum">0</span>
</div>
```